# Animation in transitionFromViewController:toViewController: not showing

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am trying to build a custom container view controller and am trying to create my own animation.  I'm starting with something simple of moving the tapped cell to the center of the screen before making it zoom in by scaling and showing the new view.  I'm starting with this:

```
- (void)showDetailViewController:(UIView *)viewToAnimate {
    UIImageView *anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self screenShot:_homeViewController.view]];


    CGRect windowBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    _detailViewController.view.frame = windowBounds;
    [self addChildViewController:_detailViewController];

    // get a screenshot of the old view before pushing the new view controller

    _detailViewController.view.alpha = 0.0;
    NSLog(@"center: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(viewToAnimate.center));
    [self transitionFromViewController:_homeViewController toViewController:_detailViewController duration:0.5 options:0 animations:^{

        CGPoint windowCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(windowBounds), CGRectGetMidY(windowBounds));
        viewToAnimate.center = windowCenter;            
    viewToAnimate.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(2, 2, 2);

            NSLog(@"center 2 : %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(viewToAnimate.center));
        _detailViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [anImageView removeFromSuperview];
    }];

    [_detailViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

What I don't understand is, if I comment out the _detailViewController.view.alpha = 0 and _detailViewController.view.alpha = 1, I don't get any animation.  It just jumps to the new childViewController.  But with those two lines, I do see an animation.  Why is that?  Thanks.

Edit: 
This is how I set up a container controller:
In viewDidLoad of ContainerViewController:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
_homeViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
_homeViewController.homeViewControllerDelegate = self;
_detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];

[self setSubViewControllers:@[ _homeViewController, _detailViewController]];

_selectedViewController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[self addChildViewController:self.selectedViewController];
[self.view addSubview:_selectedViewController.view];
[self didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Is it the right animation or just an animation?

Comment: @Tony The animation is fine for now.  I'm still tweaking it.  But I only see if I have those .alpha statements in there.  Otherwise no animation is seen on screen which is weird.

Comment: does center actually change?

Comment: @foggzilla yes center changes.

Comment: Sounds as if changes on layer properties are directly regarded as animations when transitionFromViewController animates.

Comment: What view are you passing in to animate? I see that you create an image view, and that you remove it from the superview, but I don't see where you ever added it to the superview.

Comment: @rdelmar Yeah sorry I got rid of the imageView because I wasn't actually using it yet.

Comment: Usually, when you do this kind of transition, you're transitioning from the current view (homeViewController's view) to the newly added view (detailViewController's view), so I don't understand what you're doing with viewToAnimate. What is that?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, you show yourself adding _detailViewController as a child view controller, but don't show the step of adding _homeViewController as a child view controller of self. At the point when the code you posted is executed, is _homeViewController a child of self (the view controller that is running the transition)? It needs to be.

Comment: Yes the _homeViewController is a child of the container view controller.  Actually the _detailViewController is also.  I'm just getting started with a containment view controller hierarchy so maybe I wasn't supposed to add them both at the beginning?  I added code that shows where I added them.  If that part is incorrect, please correct me!